# Unity3d new Input system increase/decrease value in steps instead of 0 to 1 or -1 immediately

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using 1D axis for the movement but the value changes immediately from 0 to 1 or -1 I need gradual increase and decrease in the value just like Input.GetAxis() and not like Input.GetAxisRaw();[image]

right now I am reading the input like this

```
float value = controlSystem.DroneInput.Throttle.ReadValue<float>();
drone.AddRelativeForce(0, value * throttle * 100, 0, ForceMode.Force);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`Mathf.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html) for doing simple easing like this:

(code adopted from docs page linked above)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    float smoothTime = 0.3f;
    float smoothingV = 0.0f;
    float currentValue = 0.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        float target = controlSystem.DroneInput.Throttle.ReadValue<float>();
        currentValue = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentValue, target, ref smoothingV, smoothTime);

        drone.AddRelativeForce(0, newValue * throttle * 100, 0, ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just simply added

```
        value += controlSystem.DroneInput.Throttle.ReadValue<float>() * 0.05f;
        value = Mathf.Clamp(value, -1, 1);
        drone.AddRelativeForce(0, value * throttle, 0, ForceMode.Force);
```

I was looking for any built in option inside Input system so far could not find it but this code works fine